# Adding ISNULL to order by kills performance

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, query-optimization

Part of my query is:

```
         select a.*, sum(case isneg when 2 then -paymentamount else amount end) over(order by coalesce(b.paymentdate, a.paymentdate)) as running_sum,
         row_number() over(order by coalesce(b.paymentdate, a.paymentdate)) as rn
         from Cheques a
            left join b on b.code = a.code
         where customercode = @customercode
```

If I replace the `coalesce(b.paymentdate, a.paymentdate)` with just b.paymentdate then my Estimated Subtree Cost in the execution plan decreases dramatically.  Is this because coalesce is a function call and is there a more performant way to do this?

Table b is a select with a max and a group by.

Comment: Presumably SQL Server has a readily available index it can use when ordering by just one of those columns, meaning that it can use that index to help the ordering. The `COALESCE` however, would mean that the database can't use that index.

Comment: To help you with your [tag:query-optimization] question, we need to see your table definitions, your index definitions, and the output of EXPLAIN. Please [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/query-optimization/info), then [edit] your question. And, if you use SSMS -- Microsoft's SQL Server Management Studio -- this tip is for you: Right-click in a query window, then select Show Actual Execution Plan, then run the query. The execution plan display sometimes recommends a new index to create.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you didn't provide the query plan, I am assuming that the difference in the estimated subtree cost between using `coalesce(b.paymentdate, a.paymentdate)` and `b.paymentdate` in your query is likely due to the optimizer's estimation based on the complexity of the expression.

`COALESCE` is a function that evaluates multiple expressions and returns the first non-null value. In your case, it will check if `b.paymentdate` is null and if so, it will use `a.paymentdate` instead. To go deeper and simulate how it is doing, the function call itself incurs some overhead in terms of CPU cycles.

If are sure that `b.paymentdate` will always have a non null value whenever it is joined with `Cheques`, you can just replace `coalesce(b.paymentdate, a.paymentdate)` with just `b.paymentdate`. This will make it simpler and potentially improve the performance of your query.

However, if `b.paymentdate` can be null in some cases, and you want to fallback to `a.paymentdate` when that happens, then in this case using `COALESCE` is mandatory.

As for optimizing , you mentioned that table `b` is derived from a select with a `MAX` and `GROUP BY`. In this case, make sure that you have the appropriate indexes on the columns used in the join (`Cheques.code` and `b.code`). Same thing for the grouping and filtering columns (`b.paymentdate`, `a.paymentdate`, and `customercode`).